# JWT token validation ASP.NET Core webapi

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I am writing an application ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API. It will receive a JWT token.

What is the best practice to validate Signature, TTL, issuer? Please advice.

```
public class Request
{
    [Required]
    [FromHeader]
    public string? UserAuthorization { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet()]
public IActionResult Get(Request req)
{
}
```

Comment: `builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCertificate();` `UseAuthentication` is required to set `HttpContext.User` to a `ClaimsPrincipal` created from the `certificate`. [`For example you could check here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-certificate-validation)

Comment: Sorry, Why certificate. I just want to validate JWT token coming in http header (UserAuthorization).

Comment: Please pay attention to correct [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Oh I see but in your question you have pointed about signature, anyway, for `Jwt validation` you can [`have a look here`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: I found one example but not sure why it's using AuthorizeAttribute and JwtMiddleware. I think we can use only one. Please advice

Comment: You can use ` [Authorize]` attribute to achieve that